# .bash_history in BINARY

Tags: linux, text, terminal, binary, ubuntu-16.04

Hello I was trying to see my terminal history using the command:

```
subl .bash_history
```

but when I opened the file .bash_history, it appeared like this:

```
2d2a 0a73 7564 6f20 6170 742d 6765 742d
7265 706f 7369 746f 7279 2070 7061 3a67
7261 7068 6963 732d 6472 6976 6572 732f
7070 610a 7375 646f 2061 6464 2d61 7074
```

I used nautilus to navigate and saw that ubuntu thinks its a binary file.
How do I make the history get back to normal? Which is text like this

```
sudo apt-get do-this
```

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS

Thank you for the time.

Comment: Can you run the command `head -3 ~/.bash_history` and update the question with its output? thanks

Comment: @Cœur it is done, my good sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION
I deleted the .bash_history file and rebooted. I had saved the history on file (which was the history the terminal printed with the command "history"). When the pc booted the file was in plain text, but all the history previous to the last session was gone. I thought it would happen so I used the file and added it to the .bash_history.